# How to remove jQuery UI Slide effect square when toggle

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am working on a simple menu, playing with jQuery - How do I remove the square background and make everything much more smooth when toggeling the "slide" effect?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.sidebar1 a').click(function(){

        var ssbar = $(this).attr('href'); 

        $(ssb1).toggle('slide');

        return false;

    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p96k9x67/

I tried using:

transition: .15s linear;
transform-origin: 19px 19px;

on the `main-content`class 
But this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull it off with this:

```
.sidebar1 {
    z-index: 1;
}
.main-wrapper > .ui-effects-wrapper {
    width: 0 !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Please note that the use of `!important` is to override inline styles added by jQuery UI.  The express purpose of `!important` is to override cascade order, so this falls in line with acceptable use of the modifier.  The root cause of the issue is that the green line element flows around the sidebar when it appears (probably because of the `flex` display styles).

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zczwjdrw/1